# Install APC on Solaris

Tags: php, solaris, php.ini, phpinfo

I Apache and PHP 5.3 installed from Blastware. I run

```
pecl install apc
```

and everything went ok. apc.so is in the extension library. I declared the extension in php.ini and enabled it with 'apc.enabled=1'.

Apc it is still not loaded, not showing in phpinfo(). Why?

Of course I restarted Apache2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Solaris, but Linux uses two separate php.ini files for Apache's mod_php and command-line php. They are located at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` respectively. Probably Solaris uses two PHP configuration files too. You should check this using `find /etc -name "php.ini"`

Comment: Why I should border about the command line? I am sure the extension is declared for the mod_php part.

Comment: php.ini is only one